# Python. Обновление многоуровневого dict

Tags: python, python-3.x, коллекции, update, dict

Здравствуйте!

Вот пример данных:

```
x = {
    'a': {'z': 1},
    'b': {'z': 2},
    'c': {'z': 3},
    'd': {'z': 4},
    'e': {'z': 5},
    'f': {'z': 6}
    'g': {'z': 7}
}
```

Вот многоуровневый словарь, который повторяет ключи из словаря данных:

```
y = {
    'b': {
        'a': {},
        'e': {
            'c': {
                'd': {}
            },
            'f': {
                'g': {}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Нужно найти в словаре **y** ключи по словарю **x** и обновить в словаре **y** из словаря **x** данные.

Comment: @jfs, здесь наверное нужно выполнить рекурсивный поиск по словарю y по ключам из x, и затем обновить данные в y. как это реализовать пока не ясно (

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обходите вложенный словарь, выставляя значения из другого словаря по текущему ключу. Повторяете для вложенных непустых словарей:

```
def update(nested_dict, new_values):
    for key, value in nested_dict.items():
        if value:
            update(value, new_values)
        nested_dict[key].update(new_values[key])
```

[Результат](https://ideone.com/fCwdvO):

```
{
  "b": {
    "e": {
      "z": 5,
      "f": {
        "z": 6,
        "g": {
          "z": 7
        }
      },
      "c": {
        "z": 3,
        "d": {
          "z": 4
        }
      }
    },
    "z": 2,
    "a": {
      "z": 1
    }
  }
}
```